# What are signs that you used enough or not enough wood protector outside?

Tags: windows, waterproofing, window-frame

This weekend, I did the big job of sanding down a wood window-frame and then reapplying the wood protector.

It is now raining, and my insecure brain is freaking out that I might not put down a good enough coat.

So what are signs that there is not enough of the wood protector? Or what are signs that show that the coat is enough?

The product
[image]

The Window
[image]

Comment: It really depends on the product and the situation. Some will bead well, some won't. You'll know in 20 years.

Comment: yeah that does suck. I would have loved to know before I got mold in my walls.

Comment: Which wood protector did you use exactly? Every brand is going to have it's own set of instructions so assuming you followed the instructions then I'm not sure what you expect from us. You didn't even provide a picture so that we can provide feedback, you've only shared your neuroticism.

Comment: Used Techniseal https://www.rona.ca/en/techniseal-maintenance-free-wood-protector-144-323-79245029 Instructions are basically 'Give a good coat'. Maybe because I'm a programmer but I kinda hate that its not a hard number lol.

Comment: I can't seem to find the manual for your product. Anyways, products like [Cabot](https://www.cabotstain.com/pdf/Clear-Wood-Protector-2101-Series.pdf) says "do not overapply" along with "re-apply every 1-3 years" and [Olympic](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/4c/4c5d7ebd-eabf-4053-bed0-5a2e7d98b5d1.pdf) says "Apply one thin coat". Set a reminder in your phone to check the wood every 4-6 months. Test it by putting some water drops on the surface; if the drops slide off and do not get absorbed then you're good but if they get absorbed then you need to re-coat.

Comment: Okay I'll do that check next time I got a 24 sunny window that I can recoat if necessary.

Comment: If you're getting mold in your walls, it's not because you didn't seal the wooden trim well enough. It's because you (or the original installer) didn't flash _behind_ the window & trim properly and didn't caulk properly.

Comment: @FreeMan So if I fuck it up I only fuck up my window? That is gonna help my anxiety. And thanks for the TIL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That anxiety will always live with you... it's part of mixing DIY "stab in the dark" with techie OCD. (I know.)

Most important with a window frame is making sure that

- you have a generous drip edge above it,
- water can flow through/over and not sit or puddle on any horizontal surfaces
- you seal off all gaps and cracks that might lead to water running down behind the window trim or get trapped
- you apply the protector to as many surfaces of the wood as possible. If possible in the future, before installation
- apply the protector on dry wood, that is brushed or sanded clean, so that it soaks in

It's important that wood can dry after it has been exposed to water. That's the first step in preventing rot. Sun and air gaps are friends.

In terms of wear aesthetics, the quality of the product matters, but be prepared to sand and reapply every 5 years (3 - 10 really, depending on product, weather fluctuations, sun exposure, your tolerance)

And to specifically answer the question: if the water rolls off after the protector has dried (24-48hrs) you applied enough.

If the coats feel like a leather layer on top of the wood, it was too much. They can flake off in stead of wear off. The wood will be bare underneath flaked-off patches, whereas wear is more gradual and will provide residual protection within the grain.

The coat(s) should be gripped into the wood and be textured like the wood grain underneath it.

Comment: Yeah that window is OLD. Like we are wondering if it is original to the house OLD. (We don't have the budget to replace them this year so we are doing the treatment to give us the few years to have the budget to replace. The old one was peeling so we needed to do something about it.) So everything of placement and how its made should be good. But yeah, I'll have to keep an eye on it.

Comment: @Fredy31 Yes the peeling parts need the most attention. As long as they are sanded so that only firmly attached patches remain, that's your best bet. Wood protection can last the upper end of the manufacturer's range, when on vertical surfaces with no water run-off dripping over it.

Comment: I busted my ass probably more than I needed to and sanded the whole window, except some small bits where the old did not want to go. Then treated everything.  The old treatment was some ugly red matte paint and our new is a tint of brown closer to wood so we cant really just patch the small places where it did peel off.

Comment: Think I can put my unrest to rest. It stopped raining maybe 30-45 minutes ago and I went to touch the wood. Its dry. Guess its a good sign that the water just slipped off and was not just absorbed into the wood.

Comment: @Fredy31 You could add a picture of your work into your question. It would allow people to spot things which you might not be considering.

Comment: Good idead @MonkeyZeus. So it seems the wood protector is working but it has a blotchy look, likely because the wood was not sanded bare. A protector works more like a stain not a paint. Where there was residue of previous paint it would soak in less. Also, next time get a roll of cheap wide painter's tape and mask off the edge to the glass and the edge to the siding.